Can you identify these two characters from the Mario Kart 8 loading screen?
I always wonder what characters these two are in the red marking.



Can you identify these two characters from the Mario Kart 8 loading screen?

Did you consider cross-checking the Mario Kart 8 roster yourself?

The inkling girl seems to wear headphones, right? This heavily distracted me...

The first one is Inkling Girl, from the Splatoon franchise.

The second one is Isabelle from Animal Crossing.


And the reason they appear in the loading screen is that they are playable in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe. (Isabelle is also playable in the Wii U version of Mario Kart 8, but had to be bought as DLC.)

They are Inkling girl from Splatoon and Isabelle from Animal Crossing.

When I went to answer the question, your answer hadn’t posted  yet. When I posted my answer, I saw that yours had been posted a minute before mine. What should I do it (my answer)?

@Daemons its fine. This happens sometimes - we have a famous scenario of this on this site where I was involved! Usually when people post answers this close together in time, the community is ok with it.  If say you posted a day later though the same thing as pinckerman, it wouldn't bode so well. In my post... it was a 44 millisecond difference.  Your answer also provides images to help identify them, which is helpful!

@Daemons as Timmy said don't worry, I put few effort in my answer (only providing links for reference) so it was definitely improvable, like you did. I posted first but this is not a race :)
